# Clear the form fields when user clicks anywhere outside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a form I wan to clear all the fields when the user clicks anywhere outside the form. Is it possible to reset the fields whenever user clicks outside the form? How can I do it.

Comment: Please provide some html to clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reset()` and `event.currentTarget` within `click` event handler set at `document`

```
document.onclick = e => {
  if (e.currentTarget !== document.forms[0])
    document.forms[0].reset()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can :

- handle document click
- get the target of click
- if the target is not the form then trigger the reset event of the form

Trigger the reset event is more efficient than reset all element one by one. This triggered event will reset all your form element like text input, textarea, checkbox, radio button ...

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).is('#formID') && !$(target).parents().is('#formID')) {
        $('#formID').trigger("reset");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```js
$("html,body").click(function(e){
    var form = $("#formone");
    if(e.target !== form[0])
    {
        form[0].reset();
    }
})
```

```css
#formdiv
{
height:100%
width:100%;
background:red;
margin:0;
}
#formone
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:yellow;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formdiv">
<form name="formone" id="formone">
Name : <input type="text">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here with javascript code,
fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sancoLgates/81sjkow0/1/

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="" id="sanzform">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var body = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var sanzform = document.getElementById('sanzform');
body.addEventListener("click", function () {
alert("reset");sanzform.reset();}, false);

sanzform.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {ev.stopPropagation();}, false);
```